# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when trying to install an apk even after uninstalling the app with adb

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I recently got a Xiaomi F21 pro, but it came with some apps preinstalled that cannot be removed. In the Android UI, they can only be disabled. Among those apps are TikTok, Instagram and Facebook.

I have managed to remove those apps using ADB by running:

```
adb shell
pm uninstall --user 0 NameOfPackage
```

Unfortunately, the alternative command without any users

```
adb uninstall NameOfPackage
```

fails with the error

```
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]
```

My goal is to install a [different version of instagram](https://www.distractionfreeapps.com/repo.html#)
When I download the apk and try to install it with adb I get the following error

```
adb: failed to install dfinsta_1_2_4.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.instagram.android signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]
```

Now what I don't understand is why it is refusing to install despite the app being already removed previously. I am suspecting the fact that adb uninstall without any user id passed to it fails to uninstall the app globally. However, I checked the users and my phone has only one.

```
adb shell pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
    Users:
        UserInfo{0:Owner:c13} running
```

What can I do here? Phone is on Android 11

Comment: If you can only disable the app it will always remain on the phone and prevents you from installing a different version. Therefore without the possibility to fully delete the pre-installed app (which requires root) you are stuck.

Comment: @Robert  I just rooted my device, entered into adb shell, ran su, then pm uninstall com.instagram.android results in the same error DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: Even if you have root permissions the system is still mounted read-only. You can try to remount it read/write. Then you can uninstall the app or you delete it's APK file.

Comment: That is exactly what I just did. Remounted / as rw though not /system because it didn't want to then went into /system/app/ and removed the folder Instagram that contained the apk. Then remount again as ro. Now I managed to install the app.